# Git queries - Git push, pull and commit. Bitbucket

Tags: angular, git, bitbucket

I've created a project repository in my Bitbucket.

I did the following,

```
git pull origin master

git commit -m "new-commit"
```

But the folder is not created in my local path.

Can anyone give step by step idea for this.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither of those commands will create a folder. What instructions are you following? What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone your directory first on your desired target from GitHub

like `git clone https://github.com/foldername/project.git`

a folder will be created

cd foldername

`git pull origin master` in your folder name

if you changed anything in your git project file

you can view the changed files by

```
git status
```

add those file to git like

```
git add filename1 filename2 filname3
```

then commit your files with an appropriate message like

```
git commit -m "my changes"
```

and then push your changes to the master branch

```
git push origin master
```

> note: if you want to create a branch from your master  after cloning
>   the git hub directory

use `git checkout -b yourbranchname`

Comment: On git pull origin master, I could only find a readme file.
How can I view the folder inside te project?

Comment: have you cloned your bitbucket file to your local? using git clone?

Comment: @VishnuNair Isn't `README.md` inside the project directory ?

Comment: Yes, the project is cloned. but my entire working folder named "project-ui" cannot be seen..

Comment: where have you cloned your project and what operating system you are using?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 is used

Comment: I think your cloning URL must not be right or there might no folders in your bitbucket directory. also, you need to check the access ask your authority to give you access to that particular repository

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to clone the remote repository to your local with the below command.

```
git clone https://git/url.git
```

That would create a copy of your repository on Bitbucket to your local path. You can then move into the folder and make your changes to the files. Once you are done with the changes, run the `git add` command to add files to the staging area. Then you can create a commit with `git commit -m "commit message"`

`git pull origin master` is to get updates from the remote repository's master branch to your local

`git commit -m "new-commit"` is to create a commit with your changes which are already staged.

Comment: @VishnuNair does the repository on Bitbucket that you have created have any files other than readme?